# HTML Contactform Security

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, email

I'm trying to send an E-Mail via HTML-Contactform.

Therefore I created this html:

```
<form id="contact_form" action="sendMail.php" method="post">
        <input id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text" placeholder="Vorname" value="Firstname">
        <input id="lastname" name="lastname" type="text" placeholder="Nachname" value="Lastname">
        <input id="mail" name="mail" type="text" placeholder="E-Mail" value="firstname.lastname@web.de">
        <textarea id="msg" name="msg" placeholder="Ihre Nachricht..." >Hallo</textarea>
        <p id="error_print" class="hidden"></p>
        <input id="contact_submit" type="submit" title="Senden">
</form>
```

I am checking the inputs via jQuery and sending it via Ajax to the PHP-File and print my errors to html.

```
$('#contact_submit').click(function(){
        var that = $('#contact_form');
        var first_name = $('#firstname').val();
        var last_name = $('#lastname').val();
        var mail = $('#mail').val();
        var msg = $('msg').val();
        if(first_name == "" || last_name == "" || mail == "" || msg == "")
        {
            $('#error_print').removeClass("hidden");
            $('#error_print').text("Bitte füllen Sie alle Felder aus");
        }
        else
        {
            if( !isValidEmailAddress(mail) ) 
            { 
                $('#error_print').removeClass("hidden");
                $('#error_print').text("Keine korrekte Mail");
            }
            else
            {
                if( !$('#error_print').hasClass( "hidden" ) )
                {
                    $('#error_print').addClass("hidden");
                }

                var url = that.attr('action'),
                    method = that.attr('method'),
                    data = {};
                that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value)
                {
                    var name = $(this).attr('name')
                        value = $(this).val();
                    data[name] = value;
                });


                //console.log(data);

                $.ajax({
                   url: url,
                   type: method,
                   data: data,
                   success: function(response)
                   {
                       $('#error_print').removeClass("hidden");
                        $('#error_print').text("Mail wurde versendet");
                   },
                   error: function(error)
                   {
                       $('#error_print').removeClass("hidden");
                       $('#error_print').text("Fehler - Bitte erneut versuchen");
                   }
                });
            }
        }
        return false;
    });
```

In my PHP I am sending the mail like this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['firstname'], $_POST['lastname'], $_POST['mail'], $_POST['msg']))
{
    $mail = htmlentities($_POST['mail'], ENT_QUOTES);
    $firstname = htmlentities($_POST['firstname'], ENT_QUOTES);
    $lastname = htmlentities($_POST['lastname'], ENT_QUOTES);
    $msg = htmlentities($_POST['msg'], ENT_QUOTES);


    $empfaenger = "empf@mydomain.de";
    $betreff = "Kontaktaufname";

    $from = "From: $fistname $lastname <$mail>";
    $text = $msg;
    //print_r($_POST);
    mail($empfaenger, $betreff, $text, $from)
}?>
```

I do not know if this is the best way to do it. For that I read a lo about injection in mails. But I am not sure if my script is safe enough.

Answer (score 0):

to send the mail you can try this below

```
<?php

ini_set("SMTP", "smtp.your_internet_service_provider.com");
ini_set("smtp_port", 25 );
ini_set("sendmail_from", "your_mail@example.com");
ini_set("auth_username", "your_mail@example.com");
ini_set("auth_password", "pwd_of_your_mail");


// For the fields $sender / $copy / $receiver, comma separated if there are multiple addresses
$sender = 'your_mail@example.com';
$receiver = 'receiver_mail@example.com';


$object = 'test msg'; 
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n"; // Version MIME
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1'."\n"; // the Content-type head for the HTML format
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$sender."\n"; // Mail reply
$headers .= 'From: "name_of_sender"<'.$sender.'>'."\n"; 
$headers .= 'Delivered-to: '.$receiver."\n"; 


$message = 'Hello from Aotoki !';
if (mail($receiver, $object, $message, $headers)) // Send message
{
    echo 'Your message has been sent ';
}
else // error
{
    echo "Your message could not be sent";
}
?>
```